# How to insert space between two values while using protractor?

Tags: javascript, date, protractor

I am creating a script to enter date in some specific field, the format it requires is MMM DD, YYYY, as you can see format has 2 spaces one between month name and date and other between comma and year. I searched so many places and tried below code but it returns value as ***NaN, 2018*** my code is listed below-

```
this.getCurrentDate = function () {
    var d = new Date();
    var currentDate = d.getDate();
    var currentMonth = d.getMonth()+1;
    var currentYear = d.getFullYear();
    if (currentDate < 10){
        currentDate = '0'+currentDate;
      }
    if (currentMonth < 10){
      currentMonth = '0'+currentMonth;
      } 
    var today = currentMonth + '\xa0' + currentDate-1 + ',' + '\xa0' +  currentYear;
    console.log(today);
    return today;

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue lies with this line of code:

```
var today = currentMonth + '\xa0' + currentDate-1 + ',' + '\xa0' +  currentYear;
```

So previously you set these two variables to strings:

```
if (currentDate < 10){
    currentDate = '0'+currentDate;
  }
if (currentMonth < 10){
  currentMonth = '0'+currentMonth;
  }
```

In the variable `today` at `currentDate` you're trying to subtract the integer 1 from a string. Hence, NaN (Not a Number).

Comment: Thanks, got it fixed.

Comment: No worries, glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are subtracting 1 from a string which is causing error.

```
        this.getCurrentDate = function () {
        var d = new Date();
        var currentDate = d.getDate();
        var currentMonth = d.getMonth()+1;
        var currentYear = d.getFullYear();
        if (currentDate < 10){
            currentDate = '0'+currentDate;
          }
        if (currentMonth < 10){
            currentDate--;  //Fixed here.
          currentMonth = '0'+currentMonth;
          } //removed -1 from current date

        var today = currentMonth + '\xa0' + currentDate + ',' + '\xa0' +  currentYear;
        console.log(today);
        return today;

    };
```

You have to subtract value from a number before you change it to a string. This will work now.

Comment: This wouldn't work all year round, if it's the 11th Month you don't subtract from the date. Personally I would make individual functions to do your logic and then return the string which you can just call in the getCurrentDate function and return the date as a string.

Comment: Hello Mike, Yes I am already fixing that thing, will surely post it here in answer once completed.